# register application with AV/AS

Tags: windows, visual-c++, antivirus

I have an application which runs on windows. I am facing following issues.

1. AV/AS blocks my application after install and when invoked first time.
2. AV/AS blocks does not allow my application to communicate with the server, it blocks my UDP/TCP connection.
3. AV/AS blocks my application access to windows registry operation.
4. AV/AS blocks my application from starting/forking new process.

To find out that why my application is misbehaving too long and it was because of AV/AS blocking it. Then I add my application in exception list of AV/AS software and it works.

Now when AV/AS software upgrade, the setting I have done in AV/AS software has to be re-done and if I forget to do it :( mess.

The question I have,

Is there any way I can register my application with the AV/AS software during my application Init function?

Is there any way I can register my application with Windows such that AV/AS comes to know my application is authentic?

I sign all my binaries with valid windows certificate.

Please let me know your suggestions.

Thanks,

~Nazir

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why AV/AS should block your application, unless it's a virus (it does something "bad"). Many antiviruses have some sort of behaviour analysis (like a sandbox) and can detect "bad" behaviour (for example if you try to overwrite some system registry, system files etc.). What exactly is your application doing? And what do you mean by "sign all my binaries with valid windows certificate" ?